# Weird slug in archives permalink

Tags: php, permalinks, archives, slug

All my wordpress installs (and some others, as I see) have the archive based index in the following format http://example.com/date/2015/06/02. But most current installs out there display it as just http://example.com/2015/06/02.

I tried disabling all plugins, changing the theme to a basic one, .htaccess is wordpress default and version is updated - and still there is no change.

What could be wrong and where should I look to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure something-- plugin, theme-- hasn't added that component? I don't recall that being the default date archive format.

Comment: Indeed, apparently it's something specific to my wordpress installs. But it's not plugin (deactivated them all) nor themes (tried with a default alternative) nor htaccess (the usual wordpress stuff). So I have no idea where it comes from :(

Comment: Ok, on further research I found that there are other sites that use this same format. I can't figure what makes the difference - mine are updated to the latest wp version (but were always like this)

Comment: Reposted [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190257/weird-slug-in-archive-permalink) with proper context, I probably should delete this one.

Comment: No. You should [edit] this one. I will close the other as a duplicate.

Comment: OK, done that. I also found the problem, "date" is added when the permalink contains post_id, else it's not.